# [Tensorflow 2.0][Tensor value printing]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

We recently ported our Tensorflow1.12.0 source code to Tensorflow2.0. During debugging, we wanted to print the value of the tensors. For example, consider the following code snippet:

```
 def __build_model():
        input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, self.__input_size), name='inputs')
        dense_layer_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.__output_size)(next_input)
        self.__model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense_layer_output)
```

In order to print the value of the tensor *input*, we just printed the variable using the *tf.print(input)* function according to [1] (previously just *print(input)*). So, the above code snippet can be re-written as follows:

```
def __build_model():
        input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, self.__input_size), name='inputs')
        dense_layer_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.__output_size)(next_input)
        tf.print(input)
        self.__model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense_layer_output)
```

However, the output that we observed is the tensor object, instead of the exact value of the input tensor. Can anyone help me with the syntax to print the exact tensor values, instead of the tensor object.

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print?version=stable

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't fed anything to your model `Input` layer produces a symbolic tensor. So you need to feed data to your model/layer to see the actual values. And `Dense` layer takes `next_input`, should it be `input`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the run time, we do provide the data, the model produces the output and everything works well (This just a small part of our code). We just wanted to print these tensor values, in case of a debugging process.

Comment: So, in the code you've provided, you are trying to get the values of the tensor during model build time. And during model build, you only have symbolic tensors. If you want to see the actual values, you need to do something like `tf.print(input(x))` where `x` is a numpy array with correct shape which passes x into the `Input` layer.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Will check your suggestion and verify